# How to sum up individual nested lists in python

Tags: python

```
    data = [[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 3], [1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2]]
```

Hello, I have this list with nested lists called data. I would like to sum up the indivual nested lists only so the output is:

```
    [[4],[2],[2],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[6],[6],[7]]
```

I tried to do this:

```
    for numbers in data:
            new_list = []
            y = sum(numbers)
            new_list.append(y) 
     print (new_list)
```

However, this only gives the sum of the last nested list, because for every for-loop the new_list seems to "reset".

Thanks

Comment: because you keep creating `new_list = []`, then appending to it, then on the next iteration, doing `new_list = []`, which discards the previous list.

Comment: As an aside, having a list with single-element lists seems pretty pointless, why not just `list(map(sum, data))`? You coudl get what you posted originally, though, with something like `[[sum(numbers)] for numbers in data]` which you coudl get in your for-loop by just doing `new_list.append([y])`

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why you would want each sum to be a single element list but you can do it in a list comprehension:

```
[ [sum(sl)] for sl in data ]
                         
[[4], [2], [2], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [6], [6], [7]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that your new_list must be outside of the loop. Right now, after each iteration, you are overwriting your new_list. Also, if you want each element to be a list you will need to change to [y]  Try to:

```
new_list = []
for numbers in data:
            y = sum(numbers)
            new_list.append([y]) 
 print (new_list)
```

Also, if you want to use python's list comprehension feature you can do:

```
new_list = [[sum(numbers)] for numbers in data]
```